# Computational Complexity of running Quicksort n times

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort

I know that Quicksort has a time complexity of Θ (nlogn). Let's say that I have two arrays, A and B, which both have n elements. If I run Quicksort to sort array B for each element of A i.e I run Quicksort n times in my program, will the time complexity of my program still be Θ (nlogn)?

Comment: Won't it be `nnlogn` ?

Comment: I just realised you're right. Thank you so much